# PyTorch AutoEncoder - Decoded output dimension not the same as input

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch, autoencoder, torchvision

I am building a Custom Autoencoder to train on a dataset. My model is as follows

```
class AutoEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AutoEncoder,self).__init__()

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 3, out_channels = 32, kernel_size=3,stride=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 32, out_channels = 64, kernel_size=3,stride=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels = 64, out_channels = 128, kernel_size=3,stride=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128,out_channels=256,kernel_size=5,stride=2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256,out_channels=512,kernel_size=5,stride=2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=512,out_channels=1024,kernel_size=5,stride=2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        )

        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=1024,out_channels=512,kernel_size=5,stride=2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=512,out_channels=256,kernel_size=5,stride=2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=256,out_channels=128,kernel_size=5,stride=2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=128,out_channels=64,kernel_size=3,stride=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64,out_channels=32,kernel_size=3,stride=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=32,out_channels=3,kernel_size=3,stride=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        )


    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        print(x.shape)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x



def unit_test():
    num_minibatch = 16
    img = torch.randn(num_minibatch, 3, 512, 640).cuda(0)
    model = AutoEncoder().cuda()
    model = nn.DataParallel(model)
    output = model(img)
    print(output.shape)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unit_test()
```

As you can see, my input dimension is (3, 512, 640) but my output after passing it through the decoder is (3, 507, 635). Am I missing something while adding the Conv2D Transpose layers ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mismatch is caused by the different output shapes of `ConvTranspose2d` layer. You can add `output_padding` of 1 to first and third transpose convolution layer to solve this problem.

i.e. `nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=1024,out_channels=512,kernel_size=5,stride=2, output_padding=1)` and `nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=256,out_channels=128,kernel_size=5,stride=2, output_padding=1)`

As per the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d):

> When stride > 1, `Conv2d` maps multiple input shapes to the same output shape. `output_padding` is provided to resolve this ambiguity by effectively increasing the calculated output shape on one side.

---

Decoder layers' shapes before adding `output_padding`:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
   ConvTranspose2d-1        [-1, 512, 123, 155]      13,107,712
              ReLU-2        [-1, 512, 123, 155]               0
   ConvTranspose2d-3        [-1, 256, 249, 313]       3,277,056
              ReLU-4        [-1, 256, 249, 313]               0
   ConvTranspose2d-5        [-1, 128, 501, 629]         819,328
              ReLU-6        [-1, 128, 501, 629]               0
   ConvTranspose2d-7         [-1, 64, 503, 631]          73,792
              ReLU-8         [-1, 64, 503, 631]               0
   ConvTranspose2d-9         [-1, 32, 505, 633]          18,464
             ReLU-10         [-1, 32, 505, 633]               0
  ConvTranspose2d-11          [-1, 3, 507, 635]             867
             ReLU-12          [-1, 3, 507, 635]               0
```

After adding padding:

```
================================================================
   ConvTranspose2d-1        [-1, 512, 124, 156]      13,107,712
              ReLU-2        [-1, 512, 124, 156]               0
   ConvTranspose2d-3        [-1, 256, 251, 315]       3,277,056
              ReLU-4        [-1, 256, 251, 315]               0
   ConvTranspose2d-5        [-1, 128, 506, 634]         819,328
              ReLU-6        [-1, 128, 506, 634]               0
   ConvTranspose2d-7         [-1, 64, 508, 636]          73,792
              ReLU-8         [-1, 64, 508, 636]               0
   ConvTranspose2d-9         [-1, 32, 510, 638]          18,464
             ReLU-10         [-1, 32, 510, 638]               0
  ConvTranspose2d-11          [-1, 3, 512, 640]             867
             ReLU-12          [-1, 3, 512, 640]               0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. But I still can't quite understand what it does. And why does it not work when I apply output_padding for the 1st and 2nd Transpose layers instead of the 1st and 3rd?

Comment: You need to manually check where to apply `output_padding` (I checked it by following the output sizes' of encoder layers) using `torchsummary` package. Applying it at the wrong place will give the wrong output shape.  It's added to right and the bottom of the image so as to arrive at the correct shape. https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-does-output-padding-exactly-do-in-convtranspose2d/2688

Comment: Read this as well: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/8816

Comment: Yep, the `torchsummary` package is really helpful for checking the sizes. Thanks a lot for your help